# Fixing Incorrect Data in Table using the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Location (LocId, StartDt,EndDt) has incorrect EndDt. The second table is how it should look. The location table is in prod Db. I'm using MS SQL Server

Table **Location** 
**LocId     StartDt                  EndDT**

1            Jan-23-2015         Dec-31-9999
1             Feb-15-2015        Dec-31-9999
2              Mar-18-2015         Apr-28-2015
2              Nov-23-2015        Dec-31-9999
2             Jul-23-2015          Nov-23-2015
2             Apr-28-2015         Dec-31-9999

This is how the final table should look which is below

**Location** 
**LocId      StartDt                  EndDT**

1              Jan-23-2015         Feb-15-2015
1              Feb-15-2015         Dec-31-9999
2              Mar-18-2015          Apr-28-2015
2              Apr-28-2015          Jul-23-2015
2             Jul-23-2015           Nov-23-2015
2             Nov-23-2015          Dec-31-9999

How should I write a select query that will get me the results as per the second table using the first one.

What steps should I perform and what would be the update query to correct the data in location table.

Comment: People aren't going to write a query for you here.  You need to take a stab at it first.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `lead()`:

```
select l.*,
       (case when enddt = '9999-12-31'
             then lead(startdt) over (partition by locid order by startdt)
             else enddt
        end) as new_enddt
from location l;
```

You can incorporate this into an update using a CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select l.*,
             (case when enddt = '9999-12-31'
                   then lead(startdt) over (partition by locid order by startdt)
                   else enddt
              end) as new_enddt
      from location l
     )
update toupdate
    set enddt = new_enddt
    where enddt <> new_enddt;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I query has NULL values for some of the dates.

Answer (score 0):

The update statement you want would look something like this:

```
UPDATE
    Tab1
SET
    Tab1.[StartDT] = Tab2.[StartDT],
    Tab1.[EndDT] = Tab2.[EndDT]
FROM
    [Location] Tab1
    JOIN [Location] Tab2
        ON Tab1.[LocId] = Tab2.[Loc2]
```

You could then use the same join for the SELECT statement.